# fun.y not recognized in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a mean line and a quintile line using `ggplot2`.

```
DF<-data.frame(DOB = c(1965, 1949, 1964, 1979, 1960, 1992, 1991, 1963, 1964, 1992, 1971, 1965),
               trip.duration.hr =c(3.36, 2.25, 5.31, 10.7, 1.96, 4.33, 23.55, 3.92, 5.46, 3.45, 13.72, 7.33))
```

I have inserted my code below. When I try to run it, it gives me the following error message:

> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
>
> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
>
> Warning messages:
>
> 1: Ignoring unknown parameters: fun.y 
>   2: Ignoring unknown parameters: fun.y 
>   3: Removed 40135 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
>   4: Removed 40135 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
>   5: Removed 40216 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

My code below:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=DOB, y=trip.duration.hr)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha=1/10) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = "mean", color="orange", size=1) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = "quantile", fun.args = list(probs = .9), linetype=2, color="red")
```

Comment: DOB is not a factor right?  The solution below should work if it is numeric

Answer (score 7):

Just replace `geom_line` with `stat_summary` including `geom = "line"` like so:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = DOB, y = trip.duration.hr)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 1/10) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = "mean", color = "orange", size = 1) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = "quantile", fun.args = list(probs = .9), linetype = 2, color = "red")
```

It will also tell you fun.y is deprecated, so I've just used fun instead.

**edit based on OP request for legend**

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  group_by(DOB) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(trip.duration.hr),
         quantile = quantile(trip.duration.hr, probs = 0.9)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(mean, quantile), names_to = "summary_stat") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DOB, y = value, group = summary_stat)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = DOB, y = trip.duration.hr), inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 1/10) +
  geom_line(aes(lty = summary_stat, col = summary_stat)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("orange", "red")) +
  labs(y = "trip.duration.hr")
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, biomiha. This worked perfectly!!

Comment: Thanks again. Is there a way for me to add labels to the two lines?

Comment: In that case I suggest you add the summary statistics as separate columns. I've edited my answer to add the legend.

Answer (score 0):

change  `geom_line(stat = 'summary'` to `stat_summary(geom ='line'` and the code will run well.

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = DOB, y = trip.duration.hr)) +
    geom_jitter(alpha = 1/10) +
    stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = "mean", color = "orange", size = 1) +
    stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = "quantile", fun.args = list(probs = .9), linetype = 2, color = "red")
```